# Как реализовать добавление новостей в Android приложение?

Tags: java, android, rest

Добрый день! 
Имеется некое приложение в котором необходимо реализовать добавление новостей. 
Новости хранятся на сервере. Использую Retrofit для для связывания с api сервера. 
В качестве макета экрана используется Fragment на весь экран. Каждая новость выводится в CardView. В xml фрагмента вставил пару CardView.
На данный момент получается получить массив объектов News, вытащить данные и отобразить в CardView. 
Но как сделать автоматическое добавление CardView?
Подскажите в чем будет недостаток такого подхода, или если это приемлемый вариант, то укажите куда дальше копать чтобы реализовать ленту новостей на подобии как в вк или других соц сетях.

Comment: Что понимается под автоматическим добавлением.  У вас же список через Recyclerview/ListView реализован? Скачивайте новые новости и добавляете их в адаптер.

Comment: список у меня еще не реализован. Вот как раз думал за RecyclerView. 
Но у меня еще несколько вопросов созрело. 
1. Когда я делаю запрос на список новостей
 @GET("/api/news")
        Call<NewsRootAllNews> getAllNews(); 
Пока на сервере добавлено все пара новостей для теста. Я их получаю в списке. Но что будет когда новостей будет много? Как мне организовать без тормозов все это? 
2. Новости где то надо хранить(бд etc.) ? 
Вообще задача довольно стандартная, многие приложения реализовывают это. Не знаете где можно почитать что то насчет архитектуры реализации этой задачи?

Comment: Зачем ставить телегу впереди лошади? Почитайте про списки и я думаю первый вопрос отпадет сам. Остальные вопросы неоднократно здесь обсуждались. К тому же многое зависит от конкретной ситуации. Нет одного верного способа что то реализовать.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо